# Searching for multiple items within a cell and returning one value

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to find a way for excel to search through cells in a column of references with references separated in the cell by () and return only the most recent year of publication.  I would like not to have to do this manually by going through 1000+ cells for 15 columns.  Is there a way to do this? Row examples 1-7 below:

```
X (BFP 2013) (Burns 1982 [1,2,3,4,S,M,H,C]) (Rooney 1984 [5,6,11,S,M,H,C])
X (BFP 2013) (Burns 1982 [1,2,3,4,S,M,H])(Rooney 1984 [5,6,11,S,M,H])
X (BFP 2013) (Lortie et al. 1996) (Burns 1982 [1,2,3,4,S,M,C])(Rooney 1984 [5,6,11,S,M,H])
#N/A
#N/A
X (Burns 1982 [1,2,3,4,S,M,H])(Rooney 1984 [5,6,11,S,M,H])
X (BFP 2013) (Burns 1982 [2,4,M,H])(Rooney 1984 [5,6,M,H])
```

For example, in this case I would like to have the formula return 2013 for the first three rows, N/A would be fine for row 4 and 5 because there is no data , and return 1984 for row six and 2013 for row seven as they are the most recent publications.

I have a list of 18 years (publications) that I can search for within the cells.  Not sure if a nested If function can pick out a year, if it occurs, within a cell and return the highest value of : 1901, 1927, 1938, 1978, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1990, 1994, 1996, 1998, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2010, 2012, 2013.

OR I am unsure if I can use an =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH  and get it to recognize just the years within a string of text and return only the most recent year.  Anyone have any ideas?  I hope this is clear enough, it is very hard to describe.
Thank you for your time,
Mags

Comment: Is what you show in one row in the data sample in one cell or distributed across cells in different columns?

Answer (score 0):

I would not like to try and do this with an excel formula as it really does not have good search and replace capability. You doubtless could do it with a macro but a more time effective to your solution might be

1. Cut and paste the column of data into a text editor which can do a grep search, like BBEdit or TextWrangler
2. Run a replacement which converts the text into a string of dates. The following more or less does what you want - search string: .*?([\d]{4}|\r) replace string \1, This gives you rows like this ,2013,1982,1984,
3. Run replacements to add "=max(" at the start of the line and ")" at the end thus giving you a text file consisting of rows such as: =max(2013,1982,1984)
4. cut and paste this back into excel

I find combining excel and BBEDit in this sort of way allows me to clean up data sets very effectively. If you need to repeat the same process then you can save the set of replacements as a text factory.

Comment: Thank you for the time, but I got a formula on another forum =MAX(IFERROR(1*MID(C3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(C3))),4),"")) and it worked great.  Now for me to learn just what it all does so I can get closer to solving my own problems next time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first `X` is in A1, I suggest entering your 18 years, one each, into ColumnsB:S of a new Row1. In B2, copied down and across to suit:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B$1,$A2)),"",B$1)
```

in T2 and copied down to suit:

```
=MAX(B2:S2)
```

This will return `0` rather than #N/A but you could wrap the MAX function to test for `0` and if so return `#N/A` if required.

However I do not understand your reference to "for 15 columns". If that is fifteen times the data of the type in ColumnA it might be worth copying or moving such blocks into ColumnA and extending the range to which the formulae apply.

Answer (score 0):

Not taking credit for the answer here but I noticed Mags (OP) already commented that he/she got the answer/working formula, I just wanted to highlight it since I missed it myself at first. a smart use of `ROW()` imho. definitely going to remember this one.

`=MAX(IFERROR(1*MID(C3,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(C3))),4),""))`